# How to tell API version from Zend routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-rest, zend-rest-route

I recently picked up a client's old project. It was originally developed using Zend framework, which is a new one to me. I'm trying to modify the correct file but they have three versions of the API.

in the module.config they have the route as:

```
'api.rest.social-credential' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/social-credential[/:social_credential_id]',
                    'scheme' => 'http',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Api\\V1\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\Controller',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

To me this means the controller I should be looking at is v1 or `Api\\V1\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\Controller` However, when looking through the code and seeing how the server responds it is clearly running v3.

The two Controllers are defined as follows:
v1

```
'Api\\V1\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\Controller' => array(
            'listener' => 'Api\\V1\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\SocialCredentialResource',
            'route_name' => 'api.rest.social-credential',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'social_credential_id',
            'collection_name' => 'social_credential',
            'entity_http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'PATCH',
            ),
            'collection_http_methods' => array(),
            'collection_query_whitelist' => array(),
            'page_size' => '25',
            'page_size_param' => '',
            'entity_class' => 'Api\\V1\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\SocialCredentialEntity',
            'collection_class' => 'Api\\V1\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\SocialCredentialCollection',
            'service_name' => 'SocialCredential',
        ),
```

v3

```
'Api\\V3\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\Controller' => array(
            'listener' => 'Api\\V3\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\SocialCredentialResource',
            'route_name' => 'api.rest.social-credential',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'social_credential_id',
            'collection_name' => 'social_credential',
            'entity_http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'PATCH',
                1 => 'DELETE',
            ),
            'collection_http_methods' => array(),
            'collection_query_whitelist' => array(),
            'page_size' => '25',
            'page_size_param' => '',
            'entity_class' => 'Api\\V3\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\SocialCredentialEntity',
            'collection_class' => 'Api\\V3\\Rest\\SocialCredential\\SocialCredentialCollection',
            'service_name' => 'SocialCredential',
        ),
```

I find nothing in the module.config that makes me believe that v3 should be the target other then this definition existing. Either I'm missing something or I don't understand how Zend routing works. Could someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it, the default_version under zf-versioning

```
'zf-versioning' => array(
        'uri' => array(
            ...
            13 => 'api.rest.social-credential',
        ),
        'default_version' => 3,
    ),
```

More info here: https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-versioning